# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;

Tags: java, android, gson

I have a fragment that returns a list from the server and the error that was showing up was this:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava / lang /
>   invoke / MethodType;

Follows all the errors below:

```
04-12 15:22:38.272 30650-30793/br.com.sys.life.atendimento I/HTTP_POST: 1 URL: http://somelink/rest/Agendamento/listarAgendamentos
04-12 15:22:38.272 30650-30793/br.com.sys.life.atendimento I/HTTP_POST: JSON: {"cdProfissional":4}
04-12 15:22:38.337 30650-30793/br.com.sys.life.atendimento I/HTTP_POST: Result: {"retornoMensagem":{"dsTitulo":"Listar Agendamentos.","dsMensagem":"SUCCESS.","dsStackTrace":null,"idCamada":"SUCCESS"},"retorno":[{"cdAgendamento":18,"itemAgenda":{"agenda":{"cdAgenda":6,"profissional":{"cdProfissional":4,"nmProfissional":"PROFISSIONAL SAUDE","idConselho":null,"nrConselho":null,"dtCadastro":null,"imgProfissional":null,"idStatus":null,"dsEmail":null,"dsSenha":null,"nmLogin":null,"idEspecialidade":null,"nrCpf":null,"nrRg":null,"nrCns":null,"dsTokenAcesso":null,"dtValidadeTokenAcesso":null,"retonaChaveAcessoWbs":null,"dsChaveAcessoWbs":null},"dtValidadeInicio":null,"dtValidadeFim":null,"hrInicio":null,"hrFim":null,"nrPacientes":null,"tpAgenda":null,"idSeg":null,"idTer":null,"idQua":null,"idQui":null,"idSex":null,"idSab":null,"idDom":null,"idStatus":null,"dtCadastro":null},"cdItemAgenda":141,"dtConsulta":"12/04/2018 00:00:00 -0300","hrConsulta":"08:00","idStatus":null},"paciente":{"cdPaciente":4,"nmPaciente":"PACIENTE TESTE","nmMae":null,"dtNascimento":"10/11/1990 00:00:00 -0200","dtCadastro":null,"tpSexo":"M","dtAtualizacao":null,"dsEmail":null,"dddCelular":null,"nrTelefoneCelular":null,"dddResid":null,"nrTelefoneResid":null,"dsLogradouro":null,"nrResidencia":null,"dsComplemento":null,"dsBairro":null,"dsMunicipio":null,"nrCep":null,"imgPaciente":null,"idStatus":null,"nrCpf":null,"nrRg":null,"nrCns":null},"dtAgendamento":null,"idStatus":"AGENDADO","tpAgendamento":null,"dtAtualizacao":null,"dsObservacao":null,"idClassificacao":"EMERGENCIA"},{"cdAgendamento":19,"itemAgenda":{"agenda":{"cdAgenda":6,"profissional":{"cdProfissional":4,"nmProfissional":"PROFISSIONAL SAUDE","idConselho":null,"nrConselho":null,"dtCadastro":null,"imgProfissional":null,"idStatus":null,"dsEmail":null,"dsSenha":null,"nmLogin":null,"idEspecialidade":null,"nrCpf":null,"nrRg":null,"nrCns":null,"dsTokenAcesso":null,"dtValidadeTokenAcesso":null,"retonaChaveAcessoWbs":null,"dsChaveAcessoWbs":null},"dtValidadeInicio":null,"dtValidadeFim":null,"hrInicio":null,"hrFim":null,"nrPacientes":null,"tpAgenda":null,"idSeg":null,"idTer":null,"idQua":null,"idQui":null,"idSex":null,"idSab":null,"idDom":null,"idStatus":null,"dtCadastro":null},"cdItemAgenda":144,"dtConsulta":"12/04/2018 00:00:00 -0300","hrConsulta":"09:00","idStatus":null},"paciente":{"cdPaciente":4,"nmPaciente":"PACIENTE TESTE","nmMae":null,"dtNascimento":"10/11/1990 00:00:00 -0200","dtCadastro":null,"tpSexo":"M","dtAtualizacao":null,"dsEmail":null,"dddCelular":null,"nrTelefoneCelular":null,"dddResid":null,"nrTelefoneResid":null,"dsLogradouro":null,"nrResidencia":null,"dsComplemento":null,"dsBairro":null,"dsMunicipio":null,"nrCep":null,"imgPaciente":null,"idStatus":null,"nrCpf":null,"nrRg":null,"nrCns":null},"dtAgendamento":null,"idStatus":"AGENDADO","tpAgendamento":null,"dtAtualizacao":null,"dsObservacao":null,"idClassificacao":"EMERGENCIA"}]}
04-12 15:22:38.344 30650-30650/br.com.sys.life.atendimento E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
04-12 15:22:38.388 30650-30793/br.com.sys.life.atendimento E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                                                                                    Process: br.com.sys.life.atendimento, PID: 30650
                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;
                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:109)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:52)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:802)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:868)
                                                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
                                                                                        at br.com.sys.life.atendimento.communication_service.utils.GsonUtil.parseJsonObjectToObject(GsonUtil.java:201)
                                                                                        at br.com.sys.life.atendimento.communication_service.utils.GsonUtil.parseStringJsonToObject(GsonUtil.java:103)
                                                                                        at br.com.sys.life.atendimento.service_atendimento.BaseService.executaPost(BaseService.java:111)
                                                                                        at br.com.sys.life.atendimento.service_atendimento.services.ServiceAgendamentoVo.consultaAgendamentos1(ServiceAgendamentoVo.java:36)
                                                                                        at br.com.sys.life.atendimento.fragments.FragmentFilaAtendimento$AsyncTaskListaAtendimentos.doInBackground(FragmentFilaAtendimento.java:129)
                                                                                        at br.com.sys.life.atendimento.fragments.FragmentFilaAtendimento$AsyncTaskListaAtendimentos.doInBackground(FragmentFilaAtendimento.java:111)
                                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
04-12 15:22:38.388 30650-30793/br.com.sys.life.atendimento E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.invoke.MethodType" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/br.com.sys.life.atendimento-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.sys.life.atendimento-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.sys.life.atendimento-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.sys.life.atendimento-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.sys.life.atendimento-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.sys.life.atendimento-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.sys.life.atendimento-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.sys.life.atendimento-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.sys.life.atendimento-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.sys.life.atendimento-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.sys.life.atendimento-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.sys.life.atendimento-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/br.com.sys.life.atendimento-1/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                            ... 36 more
04-12 15:22:38.498 30650-30650/br.com.sys.life.atendimento W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int a
```

Thinking about the error in question, I added the rows

```
builder.registerTypeAdapter(ArrayList.class, new JsonDoubleDeserializer());

builder.registerTypeAdapter(ArrayList.class, new JsonDoubleSerializer());
```

in the following `createJsonObject` method:

```
public static Gson createGsonObject() {

        // Formado de data alterado, outro formato não estava convertendo
        // Alterado para setar // na saída devido problema com WebService
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();

        builder.setDateFormat(GsonUtil.FORMAT_DATE).create();

        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Boolean.class,
                new JsonBooleanDeserializer());

        // Tratamento de BigDecimal
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(BigDecimal.class,
                new JsonBigDecimalDeserializer());

        // Tratamento de Byte[]
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(byte[].class,
                new JsonByteArrayDeserializer());

        //Tratamento de deserialização de Date java formato GMT timezone
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDateDeserializer());

        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDateSerializer());

        //TRATAMENTO DE DOUBLE
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Double.class, new JsonDoubleDeserializer());

        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Double.class, new JsonDoubleSerializer());

        //ADD TO ARRAY
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(ArrayList.class, new JsonDoubleDeserializer());

        builder.registerTypeAdapter(ArrayList.class, new JsonDoubleSerializer());

        Gson gson = builder.create();

        return gson;
    }
```

When adding these lines happened to give a conversion error, since I return a double but I ask an arraylist. If I am correct, how do I convert json to return an arraylist?

Here's methods:

```
   /**
     * Deserialização de ARRAY??????? Java
     */
private static class JsonDoubleSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Double> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Double aDouble, java.lang.reflect.Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        if (aDouble == aDouble.longValue())
            return new JsonPrimitive(aDouble.longValue());
        return new JsonPrimitive(aDouble);
    }
}
    // ARRAYLIST ?????????????????????????????
    private static class JsonDoubleDeserializer implements
            JsonDeserializer<Double> {

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         *
         * @see
         * com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer#deserialize(com.google.gson.JsonElement
         * , java.lang.reflect.Type, com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext)
         */
        @Override
        public Double deserialize(JsonElement arg0,
                                  java.lang.reflect.Type arg1, JsonDeserializationContext arg2)
                throws JsonParseException {

            String value = arg0.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString();

            return new Double(value);
        }
    }
```

Here is my fragment:

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

......
        ProfissionalVo profissionalVo = new ProfissionalVo();
        profissionalVo.setCdProfissional(4);
        new AsyncTaskListaAtendimentos(FragmentFilaAtendimento.this.getFragmentManager(), false).execute(profissionalVo);

    }

private class AsyncTaskListaAtendimentos extends BaseAsyncTask<ProfissionalVo,Void,AsyncTaskResult<RetornoAgendamentoVo>>{

    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private ProfissionalVo profissionalVo;

    public AsyncTaskListaAtendimentos(FragmentManager fragmentManager, boolean isDialogShow) {
        super(fragmentManager, isDialogShow);
        this.mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;

    }

    @Override
    protected AsyncTaskResult doInBackground(ProfissionalVo... profissionalVos) {

        try {
            profissionalVo = profissionalVos[0];

            RetornoAgendamentoVo retorno = ServiceAgendamentoVo.getInstance(MyApplicationInstance.getInstanceApplicationSingleton().getDsChaveAcessoWbs())
                    .consultaAgendamentos1(profissionalVo);

            return new AsyncTaskResult<RetornoAgendamentoVo>(retorno);
        }catch (Exception e){
            return new AsyncTaskResult<Retorno>(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(AsyncTaskResult<Retorno> respProfissionalVO) {
        super.onPostExecute(respProfissionalVO);

        if (respProfissionalVO.getExceptionResult() == null && getActivity() != null){
            retornoAgendamentoVo = (RetornoAgendamentoVo) respProfissionalVO.getResult();
            agendamentoVos = new ArrayList<>();
            agendamentoVos = retornoAgendamentoVo.getRetorno();
            // specify an adapter (see also next example)
            mAdapter = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapterFila(agendamentoVos,
                    (AppCompatActivity) getActivity(), this);
        }

    }
}
```

JSON:

```
Result: {"retornoMensagem":{"dsTitulo":"Listar Agendamentos.","dsMensagem":"SUCCESS.","dsStackTrace":null,"idCamada":"SUCCESS"},"retorno":[{"cdAgendamento":18,"itemAgenda":{"agenda":{"cdAgenda":6,"profissional":{"cdProfissional":4,"nmProfissional":"PROFISSIONAL SAUDE","idConselho":null,"nrConselho":null,"dtCadastro":null,"imgProfissional":null,"idStatus":null,"dsEmail":null,"dsSenha":null,"nmLogin":null,"idEspecialidade":null,"nrCpf":null,"nrRg":null,"nrCns":null,"dsTokenAcesso":null,"dtValidadeTokenAcesso":null,"retonaChaveAcessoWbs":null,"dsChaveAcessoWbs":null},"dtValidadeInicio":null,"dtValidadeFim":null,"hrInicio":null,"hrFim":null,"nrPacientes":null,"tpAgenda":null,"idSeg":null,"idTer":null,"idQua":null,"idQui":null,"idSex":null,"idSab":null,"idDom":null,"idStatus":null,"dtCadastro":null},"cdItemAgenda":141,"dtConsulta":"12/04/2018 00:00:00 -0300","hrConsulta":"08:00","idStatus":null},"paciente":{"cdPaciente":4,"nmPaciente":"PACIENTE TESTE","nmMae":null,"dtNascimento":"10/11/1990 00:00:00 -0200","dtCadastro":null,"tpSexo":"M","dtAtualizacao":null,"dsEmail":null,"dddCelular":null,"nrTelefoneCelular":null,"dddResid":null,"nrTelefoneResid":null,"dsLogradouro":null,"nrResidencia":null,"dsComplemento":null,"dsBairro":null,"dsMunicipio":null,"nrCep":null,"imgPaciente":null,"idStatus":null,"nrCpf":null,"nrRg":null,"nrCns":null},"dtAgendamento":null,"idStatus":"AGENDADO","tpAgendamento":null,"dtAtualizacao":null,"dsObservacao":null,"idClassificacao":"EMERGENCIA"},{"cdAgendamento":19,"itemAgenda":{"agenda":{"cdAgenda":6,"profissional":{"cdProfissional":4,"nmProfissional":"PROFISSIONAL SAUDE","idConselho":null,"nrConselho":null,"dtCadastro":null,"imgProfissional":null,"idStatus":null,"dsEmail":null,"dsSenha":null,"nmLogin":null,"idEspecialidade":null,"nrCpf":null,"nrRg":null,"nrCns":null,"dsTokenAcesso":null,"dtValidadeTokenAcesso":null,"retonaChaveAcessoWbs":null,"dsChaveAcessoWbs":null},"dtValidadeInicio":null,"dtValidadeFim":null,"hrInicio":null,"hrFim":null,"nrPacientes":null,"tpAgenda":null,"idSeg":null,"idTer":null,"idQua":null,"idQui":null,"idSex":null,"idSab":null,"idDom":null,"idStatus":null,"dtCadastro":null},"cdItemAgenda":144,"dtConsulta":"12/04/2018 00:00:00 -0300","hrConsulta":"09:00","idStatus":null},"paciente":{"cdPaciente":4,"nmPaciente":"PACIENTE TESTE","nmMae":null,"dtNascimento":"10/11/1990 00:00:00 -0200","dtCadastro":null,"tpSexo":"M","dtAtualizacao":null,"dsEmail":null,"dddCelular":null,"nrTelefoneCelular":null,"dddResid":null,"nrTelefoneResid":null,"dsLogradouro":null,"nrResidencia":null,"dsComplemento":null,"dsBairro":null,"dsMunicipio":null,"nrCep":null,"imgPaciente":null,"idStatus":null,"nrCpf":null,"nrRg":null,"nrCns":null},"dtAgendamento":null,"idStatus":"AGENDADO","tpAgendamento":null,"dtAtualizacao":null,"dsObservacao":null,"idClassificacao":"EMERGENCIA"}]}
```

Comment: You're trying to run Java 7+ code on a Java 6/Android environment. Are you using Java 8 lambda expressions in your code?

Comment: I have specified the java version in android studio, for the 8 but the error is the same.

Comment: When I leave for deserialization with an ArrayList type, it returns me the error: "Error converting data". For I do not return a type of arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating the following methods:

Deserializer:

```
 public static Gson createGsonObject() {

        // Formado de data alterado, outro formato não estava convertendo
        // Alterado para setar // na saída devido problema com WebService
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();

....

        //Array
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(List.class, new JsonArrayListDeserializer());

        Gson gson = builder.create();

        return gson;
    }

private static class JsonArrayListDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<ArrayList<T>>{

    @Override
    public ArrayList<T> deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, java.lang.reflect.Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        try {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            TypeToken<ArrayList<T>> token = new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() {};
            ArrayList<T> value = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, token.getType());

            return value;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException("Cannot parse json Boolean '"
                    + jsonElement.toString() + "'", e);
        }
    }
}
```

So it seems to me that the problem was to make json parse. With this added method, the error did not appear anymore and the data went where they should go.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is really: what version of Java APIs was your code compiled against, and what version of Java is it actually running on? Not exactly sure, but that whole java.lang.invoke package was not introduced until Java 7, I believe, so probably you're compiling against Java 7 or 8, but running on Java 6 or earlier.

Comment: I have specified the java version in android studio, for the 8 but the error is the same.

Comment: When I leave for deserialization with an ArrayList type, it returns me the error: "Error converting data". For I do not return a type of arraylist